# How divide overflow occurs when sign of the dividend is same as that of divisor?

Tags: divide, divide-by-zero, microprocessors, dividebyzeroexception

As I know, The "Divide Overflow" is an exception that occurs when you try to perform division by zero.

I was learning a tutorial about computer architecture and design and I got confused by a statement

***Divide overflow occurs when the sign of the dividend is same as that of the divisor.***

Can anyone please enlighten about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically because the quotient of the division can not represent the number.
Take a look here:
http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/COE/aimane/assembly/pagegen-71.aspx.htm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.